# Why accesing DataFrame from UDF results in NullPointerException?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a problem executing a Spark application.

Source code:

```
// Read table From HDFS
val productInformation = spark.table("temp.temp_table1")
val dict = spark.table("temp.temp_table2")

// Custom UDF
val countPositiveSimilarity = udf[Long, Seq[String], Seq[String]]((a, b) => 
    dict.filter(
        (($"first".isin(a: _*) && $"second".isin(b: _*)) || ($"first".isin(b: _*) && $"second".isin(a: _*))) && $"similarity" > 0.7
    ).count
)

val result = productInformation.withColumn("positive_count", countPositiveSimilarity($"title", $"internal_category"))

// Error occurs!
result.show
```

Error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 54.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 54.0 (TID 5887, ip-10-211-220-33.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal, executor 150): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<string>, array<string>) => bigint)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:45)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:43)
    ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:604)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<string>, array<string>) => bigint)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
  ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:45)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:43)
  ... 16 more
```

I have checked whether `productInformation` and `dict` have null value in `Columns`. But there are no null values.

Can anyone help me?
I attached example code to let you know more details:

```
case class Target(wordListOne: Seq[String], WordListTwo: Seq[String])
val targetData = Seq(Target(Seq("Spark", "Wrong", "Something"), Seq("Java", "Grape", "Banana")),
                     Target(Seq("Java", "Scala"), Seq("Scala", "Banana")),
                     Target(Seq(""), Seq("Grape", "Banana")),
                     Target(Seq(""), Seq("")))
val targets = spark.createDataset(targetData)

case class WordSimilarity(first: String, second: String, similarity: Double)
val similarityData = Seq(WordSimilarity("Spark", "Java", 0.8), 
                     WordSimilarity("Scala", "Spark", 0.9), 
                     WordSimilarity("Java", "Scala", 0.9),
                     WordSimilarity("Apple", "Grape", 0.66),
                     WordSimilarity("Scala", "Apple", -0.1),
                     WordSimilarity("Gine", "Spark", 0.1)) 
val dict = spark.createDataset(similarityData)

val countPositiveSimilarity = udf[Long, Seq[String], Seq[String]]((a, b) => 
    dict.filter(
        (($"first".isin(a: _*) && $"second".isin(b: _*)) || ($"first".isin(b: _*) && $"second".isin(a: _*))) && $"similarity" > 0.7
    ).count
)

val countDF = targets.withColumn("positive_count", countPositiveSimilarity($"wordListOne", $"wordListTwo"))
```

This is an example code and is similar to my original code.
Example code operates well. Which point should I check in original code and data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very interesting question. I have to do some search, and here is my though. Hope this will help you a little bit.

When you create `Dataset` via [createDataset](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0ffa7c488fa8156e2a1aa282e60b7c36b86d8af8/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L465), spark will assign this dataset with `LocalRelation` logical query plan.

```
def createDataset[T : Encoder](data: Seq[T]): Dataset[T] = {
    val enc = encoderFor[T]
    val attributes = enc.schema.toAttributes
    val encoded = data.map(d => enc.toRow(d).copy())
    val plan = new LocalRelation(attributes, encoded)
    Dataset[T](self, plan)
  }
```

Follow this [link](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-LogicalPlan-LocalRelation.html): 
`LocalRelation is a leaf logical plan that allow functions like collect or take to be executed locally, i.e. without using Spark executors.`

And, it's true as [isLocal](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/154351e6dbd24c4254094477e3f7defcba979b1a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L500) method point out

```
 /**
   * Returns true if the `collect` and `take` methods can be run locally
   * (without any Spark executors).
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def isLocal: Boolean = logicalPlan.isInstanceOf[LocalRelation]
```

Obviously, You can check out your 2 datasets is local.

And, the [show](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/154351e6dbd24c4254094477e3f7defcba979b1a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L234) method actually call `take` internally.

```
private[sql] def showString(_numRows: Int, truncate: Int = 20): String = {
    val numRows = _numRows.max(0)
    val takeResult = toDF().take(numRows + 1)
    val hasMoreData = takeResult.length > numRows
    val data = takeResult.take(numRows)
```

So, with those envidences, I think the call `countDF.show` is executed, it will behave simliar as when you call `count` on `dict` dataset from **driver**, number of call times is number of records of `targets`. And, the `dict` dataset of course doesn't need to be local for the show on `countDF` work.

You can try to save `countDF`, it will give you exception same as first case
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<string>, array<string>) => bigint)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two questions. 1) Your main point is, In other words, it will occur an error in the example code when I execute save or show method? I'm entry level Spark user, so I think this might be a silly question.
2) Apart from that, there is no way to use Dataframe in the udf?

Comment: 1. Your first case, both will fail. Your second case, save will fail.
2. Dataset can be in udf, i.e compile just fine. But it will be fail at runtime like your first case if the calling dataset is not local and the action is not `take` or `collect`.

Answer (score 5):

You can not use a `Dataframe` inside of an `udf`. You will need to join `productInformation` and `dict`, and do the `udf` logic after the join.

Comment: Is it possible to use immutable Map converted by dict (DataFrame) in UDF? Currently, it's difficult to join productInformation and dict.

Comment: if the `dict` df is not too big, you can collect it, convert to a `Map`, and use that map in the udf