# Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I want to get the DataSet with the following content:

```
111,Array([123,1],[222,3]
222,Array([333,3],[444,3]
```

This is my code of Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11:

```
val spark = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
                    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", inputPath)
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.parquet(inputPath)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("sample_data")
val rows = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sample_data")

val result = rows.map{ row: Row => {
     val pk = row.get(row.fieldIndex("pk")).toString.toLong

     val r = spark.sql("SELECT pk FROM sample_data WHERE pk != " + pk)
     val productList = r.rdd.map(r => r(0).toString.toLong).collect()

     (row.get(row.fieldIndex("pk")).toString.toLong, productList)
}}
```

But I get this error:

```
error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
[ERROR]       val result = rows.map{ row: Row => {
```

I tried to import `sqlContext.implicits._`, but it does not compile.

In maven I have this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE:**

Finally I imported the implicits as follows: `import spark.implicits._`, but I get this error in the runtime:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
        at org.test.Compute$$anonfun$1.apply(ComputeNumSim.scala:68)
        at org.test.Compute$$anonfun$1.apply(ComputeNumSim.scala:61)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: did you try to `import spark.implicits._`

Comment: @AlexNaspo: Yes, thanks. This worked, but I obtained another error in the runtime. Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store `RDD` in  `Dataset` or any other distributed collection in another distribute collection. You shouldn't be even possible to access `DataFrame` in `map`, but there [seems to be an interesting loophole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111607/why-does-this-spark-code-make-nullpointerexception) related to `Datasets` backed by local collections.

In this case you should `join` both `Datasets` by key:

```
rows.alias("rows").join(
  spark.table("sample_data").alias("sample"), 
  $"rows.pk" =!= $"sample.pl"
)
```

or more explicitly

```
rows.alias("rows")
  .crossJoin(spark.table("sample_data").alias("sample")) 
  .where($"rows.pk" =!= $"sample.pk")
```