# CreateDataset results in NullPointer when called inside an RDD forEach

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm writing a Spark job that downloads files from S3 that contains json lines, turns those into a DataSet and writes them to a Parquet file.

```
javaSparkContext.parallelize(files)
            .foreach((VoidFunction<String>) file -> {
                try {
                    List<String> jsons = Lists.newArrayList();
                    ... 
                    Dataset<String> eventsDS = spark.createDataset(jsons);
                    Dataset<Row> eventsDF = spark.read().json(eventsDS);
                    eventsDF.write().parquet("parquet/")
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

The error at runtime when running on my laptop

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataset(SparkSession.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataset(SparkSession.scala:494)
    at com.amazon.mobiletargeting.ParquetExporter.lambda$export$faf5744a$1(ParquetExporter.java:166)
```

My question was down voted under the pretext that its a duplicate of [Why does this Spark code make NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111607/why-does-this-spark-code-make-nullpointerexception)

I updated the comment below saying that my Spark dataSets aren't being created in the context of UDFs but inside a forEach on an RDD.

Any advise is highly appreciated!
Ranjit

Comment: Not seeing how they are related. The post you linked talks about not using DataFrames inside a UDF and I don't define a UDF - just a basic forEach on an RDD. Unless I missed a key concept that relates UDF and the 'forEach', I think my question is unrelated.

Comment: Yeah not sure why this was marked as duplicate.  Did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Comment: for anyone else landing here looking for an answer. this is how I finally got it to work after pulling various things from the examples in the example code distributed with the spark download "examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/"

messages.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

           SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(rdd.context().getConf());

List<String> jsonData = rdd.map(row -> row.value()).collect();

//do your thing 

}