# Spark: groupBy and treat grouped data as a Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataset, and I would like to group the data and process the groups, yielding zero or one element per each group. Something like:

```
val resulDataset = inputDataset
  .groupBy('x, 'y)
  .flatMap(...)
```

I didn't find a way to apply a function after a `groupBy`, but it appears I can use `groupByKey` instead (is it a good idea? is there a better way?):

```
val resulDataset = inputDataset
  .groupByKey(v => (v.x, v.y))
  .flatMap(...)
```

This works, but here is a thing: I would like process the groups as `Dataset`s. The reason is that I already have convenient functions to use on Datasets and would like to reuse them when calculating the result for each group. But, the `groupByKey.flatMap` yields an `Iterator` over the grouped elements, not the `Dataset`.

**The question**: is there a way in Spark to group an input Dataset and map a custom function to each group, while treating the grouped elements as a Dataset ? E.g.:

```
val inputDataset: Dataset[T] = ...
val resulDataset: Dataset[U] = inputDataset
  .groupBy(...)
  .flatMap(group: Dataset[T] => {
    // using Dataset API to calculate resulting value, e.g.:
    group.withColumn(row_number().over(...))....as[U]
  })
```

Note, that grouped data is bounded, and it is OK to process it on a single node. But the number of groups can be very high, so the resulting Dataset needs to be distributed. The point of using the Dataset API to process a group is purely a question of using a convenient API.

---

What I tried so far:

- creating a Dataset from an Iterator in the mapped function - it fails with an NPE from a SparkSession (my understanding is that it boils down to the fact that one cannot create a Dataset within the functions which process a Dataset; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481230/createdataset-results-in-nullpointer-when-called-inside-an-rdd-foreach?noredirect=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111607/why-does-this-spark-code-make-nullpointerexception))
- tried to overcome the issues in the first solution, attempted to create  new SparkSession to create the Dataset within a new session; fails with NPE from SparkSession.newSession
- (ab)using `repartition('x, 'y).mapPartitions(...)`, but this also yields an `Iterator[T]` for each partition, not a `Dataset[T]`
- finally, (ab)using `filter`: I can collect all distinct values of the grouping criteria into an Array (`select.distinct.collect`), and iterate this array to filter the source Dataset, yielding one Dataset for each group (sort of joins the idea of [`multiplexing` from this](http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2016/02/08/efficient-multiplexing-for-spark-rdds/) article); although this works, my understanding is that it collects all the data on a single node, so it doesn't scale and will eventually have memory issues

Comment: "I already have convenient functions to use on Datasets", Can you tell what functions do you want to use on the groupeddata? Also, if possible, can you provide sample input and expected output along with the functions you intended to reuse would help in solving your question. Thanks.

Comment: Here goes a couple of examples of the functions I want reuse. Some are from my library, like a linear interpolation on a Dataset for example (uses window functions extensively in its implementation). As of this one - the code can be technically refactored to use `window.partitionBy` and reuse the rest. Others are form a Dataset API itself and in particular - the `Dataset.summary` function which I need to use to calculate the percentiles. As of this one - it seems that API only allows applying this operation on the entire Dataset, while I would need to apply it on each group separately.