# Create new column in dataframe with udf and recursion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recursion, parquet

I have two parquet files one describe files with inode number, one describe the inode name and the parent inode, I need to reconstruct fullpath from the second file.

My table with inode's description is named `idirs_table_read` and is formated like this (this is a full example):

```
iparent,iname,ichild
93767723,folder12,40715069
65688175,level4,93767723
80373386,name,65688175
22746413,level2,80373386
24,base,22746413
```

I want with a inode number to be able to reconstruct a file path.
For example for inode 93767723, the path is : `/base/level2/name/level4`
I have define two functions (one recursive, the other procedural) those two functions works when used like this `newPathRecursive(1236549)` but fails when use in `withColumns`:

```
def newPathRecursive( inumber : Int ):String = {
    var composite = ""
    var result = idirs_table_read.select("iparent", "iname").filter($"ichild"===inumber)

    if ( (result.count() == 1) && (result.first()(0) !=  inumber) )   {
       var num= result.first()(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
       composite=  newPath(num) + "/"  + result.first()(1).asInstanceOf[String] 
    }
    return composite
}


def newPathProcedurale  (inumber : Int ):String =  {

    var composite = ""
    var go = true
    var parentInode=inumber
    while(go){

        var result = idirs_table_read.select("iparent", "iname").filter($"ichild"===parentInode)

        if ( (result.count() == 1) && (result.first()(0) !=  inumber) )   {
            println(result.first()(0)+","+ result.first()(1)+","+ parentInode)
            parentInode = result.first()(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
            composite=  "/"  + result.first()(1).asInstanceOf[String] + composite
        }else{
            go=false
        }
    }
    return composite.asInstanceOf[String]
}
val buildpath2 = udf[String, Int](newPath2)
val buildpath = udf[String, Int](newPath)
```

My goal is to be able to replace the inode number in the other table by this path, but when I try to use the function in a select I get something like that:

```
 df.withColumn("newcol",buildpath ( $"inumber" )
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1521.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1521.0 (TID 14859, ip.ip.ip.ip, executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (int) => string)
```

Could you please help me with this code and eventually advise me better implementation of this algorithm and better use for it ?
My goal is simply to build a new parquet file from those two with complete path instead of inodes (which is not human readable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this Spark code make NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111607/why-does-this-spark-code-make-nullpointerexception)

Comment: @user8371915 there's no trace of NullPointerException here Am I Wrong ?

Comment: There is no reproducible example or full tracback either and names don't match, but if `idirs_table` is a (non-local) `Dataset` then using `newPathRecursive` as an `udf` __should__ result in `NullPointerException` :) __TL;DR;__ It is not a valid pattern in Apache Spark. If you really want to use Spark take a look at graphframes - you'll need some form of iterative message passing to solve this.

Comment: @user8371915 thank you for pointing me in the right direction, still doesn't really answer my question, but the comment below the answer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the post mention as duplicate is in fact a different duplicate as mine and I didn't understand the explanation because the real answer is in a comment not in the actual answe, here's the answer:

What I want to do is not possible if the dataset used inside the udf is not local:

```
inodes_table_read.isLocal
false
```

So I'm going to use something else and I'll post the explanation.